# Talend: Aggregate mutiple XML files considering two tags

Tags: xml, talend

Good morning all,
I'm facing an issue with xml files and talend that I'm trying to solve.
I have some XLM files like below:

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <msg>
        <header>
            <Info1>inf1<Info1>
            <Info2>inf2<Info2>
            ...
        </header>
        <body>

             <Bla>bla1</Bla>

        </body>
    </msg>
</file>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <msg>
        <header>
            <Info1>inf1<Info1>
            <Info2>inf2<Info2>
            ...
        </header>
        <body>
            <Bla>bla2</Bla>

        </body>
    </msg>
</file>
```

... File n:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <msg>
        <header>
            <Info1>inf1<Info1>
            <Info2>inf2<Info2>
            ...
        </header>
        <body>
            <Bla>blaN</Bla>

        </body>
    </msg>
</file>
```

Each file has only one tag `file/msg` and one tag `file/msg/header` and can have a multiple tags `file/msg/body`.
And I need to aggregate files which have the same value for `file/msg/Info1` and `file/msg/Info2` into one file with multiple tag `file/msg/body`.

So the output file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <msg>
        <header>
            <Info1>inf1<Info1>
            <Info2>inf2<Info2>
            ...
        </header>
        <body>
            <Bla>bla1</Bla>

        </body>
        <body>
            <Bla>bla2</Bla>

        </body>
        ...
        <body>
            <Bla>blaN</Bla>

        </body>
    </msg>
</file>
```

I don't know how to achieve this, can anyone help me?

Comment: what should your end result xml file look like?  the same as the inout files but the values (numeric I assume) in Info1 and Info2 are all added together?

Comment: I changed your XML source file by replacing some "\" chars with the correct "/" chars.

Comment: @LaRoche I have updated my post. I hope it is more clear.